# Running matlab from terminal (windows) without opening a matlab command window

Tags: matlab, cmd

I am opening `cmd` on windows and running matlab using the instruction below:

```
matlab.exe -nosplash -nodesktop -nojvm -wait -logfile "log2.txt" -r simulation_f(2)
```

I would expect the `"-nodesktop"` option not to open any new window, but unfortunately the command above does open a new window (screenshot below). Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: Use `-batch` instead of all of those other arguments. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html